# T a diagonalizable linear operator on V $\implies$ By the Complex Spectral Theorem, T is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, diagonalization, gram-schmidt

**Prove if the following statement is true.**

Let V be a finite dimensional C-vector space with inner product and T a diagonalizable linear operator on V. Then there is a basis of eigenvectors of T for V. Applying the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process to this basis and then normalizing, an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for V is obtained. By the Complex Spectral Theorem, T is normal.

**Attempt:**

T a diagonalizable linear operator on V if and only if T has a basis of n eigenvectors, in which case the diagonal entries are the eigenvalues for those eigenvectors. Let $\beta$ be that basis.

By Gram-Schmidt, ${\beta}'$ is an orthonormal basis of V.

Since T is diagonalizable, $[T]_{{\beta}'}$ is diagonalizable.

There exists an orthonormal basis ${\beta}'$ of V such that $[T]_{{\beta}'}$ is diagonalizable if and only if T is normal.

Therefore, the statement is true.

Am I wrong?

Comment: I suggest a more specific title for your post. Much more specific!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Is the question whether all diagonalizable linear operators $T$ on a finite dimensional complex vector space $V$ are normal? (i.e. whether you have given a proof of this?)

If so, unfortunately the answer is no. Such a linear operator $T$ is normal if and only if $T$ is unitarily diagonalizable (i.e. is diagonalized by conjugation with a unitary matrix), and this is just not the case in general.

To disprove the claim it suffices to just give an example, e.g. the matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
0&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $1$ and $2$ (check this), but is not normal.

You can try to apply your argument to this specific matrix to find out what's wrong. This issue is that $[T]_{\beta'}$ need not be a diagonal matrix, even though $[T]_\beta$ was. In my example matrix there is an eigenvector $
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix}$ with eigenvalue $1$ and an eigenvector $
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1
\end{bmatrix}$ with eigenvalue $2$, but these vectors are not orthogonal. You might be relying on a "fact" that eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal, but unfortunately this is not true in general (it holds for e.g. self-adjoint or normal matrices).

On the other hand, if we restrict $T$ to in addition be a *self-adjoint* linear operator then your argument does work, and you have given a valid proof that all self-adjoint linear operators are normal.

Comment: The question is whether the statement is true. I think it is and tried to dissect it.

Comment: @Shambhala I have edited my answer to add a counterexample.